# How do I access a private array from a subclass in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, class, subclass, private

I know its not possible to directly call private array's from within a subclass but I still need to someway to access it so what's the best way to go about this? Right now I have a class for my main method, random array, player array and a fourth class which I want to use to compare the two arrays.

So far I have tried to make a getter method which just returns the array and then I would call that getter method from the compare class. This failed so then I tried to make a basic for loop would return each value in that array but this also does not work. So my question is how can I get the the values of a private array into a subclass?

Here is one of my attempts which just prints 0 0 0 0

```
    public class test {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

      PlayerArray player = new PlayerArray(console);

      testArray test = new testArray();
      test.printArray();
    }


    class PlayerArray extends RandomArray {
       private int[] playerArray = new int[4];

       public PlayerArray() {
       }

       public PlayerArray(Scanner console) {
           System.out.println();
           System.out.println("Enter 4 numbers you wish to guess: ");
           for(int i=0; i<playerArray.length; i++) {
              playerArray[i] = console.nextInt();
           }
       }

      public int[] getPlayerArray() {
         return playerArray;
      }
    }


  class testArray extends PlayerArray {

    public void testArray() {
    }

    public void printArray() {
        System.out.println(getPlayerArray());
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            System.out.print(getPlayerArray()[i]);
        }

    }
 }
```

Comment: I have googled this problem so many times and watched tons of videos but nothing helps. Everything just talks about super basic encapsulation like where the user enters a name in a setter method and then the system prints the getter method. I am not sure why there needs to be 1000 resources on the most basic possible use of encapsulation because if people are going to struggle it will be with the difficult problems not the super easy ones...

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it.

However, `public void testArray()` does nothing - did you intend to make a constructor? Those don't have a return type, so, just `public testArray`.

Because you did not write a constructor, java made one for you. It's  equivalent to:

```
public testArray() {
    super();
}
```

as in, it calls the PlayerArray constructor that doesn't do anything, thus resulting in the playerArray holding 4x a 0 value. If you want something else, well, that `Scanner` reference isn't going to appear out of thin air, so:

```
public testArray(Scanner console) {
    super(scanner);
}
```

to invoke 'the right one'.

NB: It should be `TestArray`, and making arrays visible to externals is bad as making them public; you have no control over it, and anybody you give it to can change it with e.g. `getPlayerArray()[i] = 10;`. Generally, use Lists (`java.util.List`) and such instead of arrays.

Comment: I was using the constructor earlier so I just left it in there but I am calling all the methods from my main method. PlayerArray player = new PlayerArray(console);  testArray test = new testArray();  test.printArray();

Comment: I updated my post to reflect the main method since it was drawing some confusion but I left out my other class since it suffers from the same issue as my PlayerArray class. I am required to use a normal private array and I cant use array lists. I see what you mean by it not being that secure which is not a problem in my case but is useful information for the future.

Comment: ` PlayerArray player = new PlayerArray(console); testArray test = new testArray(); test.printArray();` Okay, now you have two separate PlayerArray objects. One with whatever values you entered, and one completely different one using that no-args constructor, thus 4x 0-values. Each instance gets its own copy. You want just one instance: `testArray ta = new testArray(console);`.

Comment: I just tried to make my playerArray static and it worked so I assume my issue had something to do with the array being treated as an object and then me not calling it correctly but I am not exactly sure.

Comment: playerArray is definitely not supposed to be static, here. Maybe you need to re-read whatever part of your course or tutorial covers Object Oriented. That, or stop extending things.

Comment: What would be the best way to go about this without using static then?

Comment: Do what I said: Stop making 2 objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
  PlayerArray player = new PlayerArray(console);
```

Here you create an instance of PlayerArray which takes in the console and populating the internal array.

```
  testArray test = new testArray();
  test.printArray();
```

Here you create a NEW instance of testArray where the internal array hasn't been populated.

For it to print the correct values you need to copy the printArray() method to the Player class and call the printArray() method on the player instance.

```
  player.printArray();
```

and just delete the testArray() instance from the Main method. It serves no purpose here.

Alternatively you can add a constructor in the Player class that takes in a Console and passes it to the Super via super(console);

Comment: I tried that and it just gave me an error since I would be using an object of the Player class to try and call the testArray class

Comment: Sorry that is correct, I had forgotten to write that you need to copy the printArray() method to the Player class first. 

I updated my answer to reflect this. 

Your problem is that you instantiate 2 different objects where one contains the actual populated array, but you call the printArray method on the other one. 

I dont see the purpose of the TestArray class so I suggest just delete that one and use the PlayerArray instead.